# Given $P : R^n → R^n$ is a linear transformation. Show that there is an integer $k$ such that $R(P^k)=R(P^{k+1})=R(P^{k+2})=...$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $P : R^n → R^n$ is a linear transformation. Show that there is an integer $k$ such that $R(P^k)=R(P^{k+1})=R(P^{k+2})=...$($R(P)$ denotes the range of $P$.)

Answer (score 4):

Well, we have inclusions $$R(P) \supseteq R(P^2) \supseteq \ldots$$And by finite dimensionality we have to stabilize (if not these subspaces decrease in dimension infinitely often).

Comment: What do you mean by 'stabilize'?

Comment: @drawar: To stabilize for a sequence means to become constant from a certain point on, here exactly the condition $R(P^k)=R(P^{k+1})=R(P^{k+2})=\ldots$ of the question.